# Edit and Continue and Test Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, tdd

Sometimes I would test my Class Library from a WinForm stub app even though I was developing it for immediate use in a web app. Calling the Class library from a WinForm app would give me the ability to be able to edit the code in the class library and continue, a feature that wasn't available in WebForm apps.

Shouldn't I be able to get the same sort of Edit and Continue functionality in a Test project as a WinForm app? I am getting the following error when I try to modify the code in either the Test class or the Class Library I am calling from it.

[image]

"Enable Edit and Continue" is set under Tools --> Options

Comment: What is the Test runner you're using? the VS built-in one? [Not helpful dept: If you're trying TDD, try improving the tests to the point (informative failures and super-fast execution times) where you don't need the debugger. Much less the edit and continue feature. I find it easier to run tests > fail > make tiny edit > run tests again > pass cycles.]

Comment: I couldn't disagree more with those who argue that debuggers shouldn't be used. There's a place for them.

Comment: I wasn't stating an absolute.. but stepping through using a debugger is an exception rather than the norm, when doing TDD. I see the need for a debugger as a sign that I don't understand how my code works... so I retrospect on why this is so.. if I've been building up from well tested blocks. e.g. TDD may hide the lack of a sophisticated debugger like VS.. (e.g. if you're working with Ruby or similar languages). But YMMV.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use edit and continue in your test environment?